# Apache httpd.conf - Link multiple domains to corresponding subfolders

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need a rule to internally rewrite several domains, with and without www:

```
www.a.com --> /m/n/o/
b.c.org --> /x/y/z/
```

The setup is Apache running locally on Windows (XAMPP). I've got the hosts file set up so all the domains point to localhost. I'd like every page to get redirected, i.e. I want to point each domain to it's own different root directory and have it work normally from there. e.g.

```
/                          <-- Top level folder, everything is under here.
   /root/of/domain/A/      <-- www.a.com
   /root/of/domain/C/      <-- b.c.org
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Are both domains `a.com` and `c.org` pointing to the same server ? Do you want to redirect only root page or every pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.

**(1)** The one you asked (**with** *mod_rewrite*)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?a\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /root/of/domain/A/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^b\.c\.org$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /root/of/domain/C/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note: don't forget to replace example values by real ones. Also, make sure *mod_rewrite* is enabled.

**(2)** the cleanest way: configure virtualhosts directly (**without** *mod_rewrite*)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "X:/path/to/root/of/domain/A/"
  ServerName a.com
  ServerAlias www.a.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "X:/path/to/root/of/domain/C/"
  ServerName b.c.org
</VirtualHost>
```